# How do I put a text exactly in the center of a table header using html table tag?

Tags: html, text, html-table, tags, web-frontend

Say I have this line of code in my table script:

```
<th rowspan="2" colspan="1">The header</th>
```

The result looks like this:
[one of the headers of my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/484WY.png)

The result I wanted is the text is centered both vertically and horizontally.

I tried class="text-center" but it only centers horizontally. Other solutions I've found only have 1 `rowspan` so it is different, I can just use text-center. I also found this `valign` which I assumed as `vertical-align` and it has the "middle" value, but it didn't work too.

How do I get the result I wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation using CSS to offset 50% from the left and top:

```
.center
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
}
```

Call the table header tag inside a div class like so:

```
<div class=center>
    <th rowspan="2" colspan="1">The header</th>
</div>
```

Comment: this kinda worked because the text was in the middle of the box. But, if I apply it to other headers as well, they stacked on top of each other. I tried deleting position: absolute; but the text just stayed at the bottom left.

Comment: @alviratulaha Try to put this after each of the div center class blocks "<div style="clear: both;"></div>"